# Get a random choice from 2 columns

Tags: python, numpy

How can I get a random choice from 2 columns?
I want to randomly get 4 cards from 2 different columns in the same csv file. I currently get 4 cards from each column separately.
I would like to use from 2 columns as one.

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.drop(['q','w'],inplace=True, axis=1)
n = 0
z = n+10
df=df.iloc[n:z]

g = df['a']
j = df['b']
#p = g+j

for i in range(5):
    cards_1 = np.random.choice(g, 4)
    print(cards_1)
print("\n")    
for ii in range(5):
    cards_2 = np.random.choice(j, 4)
    print(cards_2, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Might not be the best solution, but you could convert the columns to a list with `.tolist()` method before you do the summations you currently have commented out and then draw the  random choices from `p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Side Note*: `np.random.choice` without the parameter `replace = FALSE` might pick a single card multiple times as an object is not removed from the choice pool after it is extracted.

Consider this solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Dont worry about this. this is only to get some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(np.array(
    [[7,8,9,10, "j", "q", "k", "a"],
     [7,8,9,10, "j", "q", "k", "a"],
     [7,8,9,10, "j", "q", "k", "a"]])),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
                   
                   
# end of data
                   
# Choose two column names without replacement (dont pick same column twice or more)
random_colnames = np.random.choice(df.columns,2, replace = False)
# Custom colnames could be
#custom_colnames = ['a', 'b']


#drawn_cards = []

for col in random_colnames:
    # pick elements from column with replacement
    # and extend them to the list of already drawn cards
    for _ in range(5):
        # add replace = False if you do not want the same cardd picked more than once
        draw = np.random.choice(df[col],4)
        #drawn_cards.extend(draw) 
        print(draw)
    

# Print for showcase purpose
# print(drawn_cards)
```

Comment: Thanks
My cards are
7,8,9,10, j, q, k, a

Comment: I use np.random.choice because in random preference is more for numbers
My cards are
7,8,9,10, j, q, k, a

Comment: I edited my answer so it is more in line with your `numpy` - import. It should work regardless of the type of data. I am using `np.random.choice` as well. How you call your cards does not matter to the underlying algorithm.

Comment: Great, but I can not fit my date, and columns Thank you

Comment: And also the result comes out in 8 item instead of in 4 item. Thank

Comment: Ok, I succeeded with the data and columns
But still the result comes out 8 characters instead of 4

Comment: I have succeeded, thank you very much dear man :)

Comment: last question
I'm not succeeding with for loop to
Print 5 results

Comment: Could you please clarify how you want your output structured? It seems you want to draw 4 Cards five times from each column. After every draw, you want to print the resuting drawn cards. Do you need the information on the drawn cards after printing it? or is the print enough?

Comment: ['A', 'K', 'Q', '9']
['K', 'J', '7', 'Q']

Comment: one after the other

Comment: One after the other goes down

Comment: ['K', 'J', '7', 'Q']

Comment: ['J', 'J', '7', '10']

Comment: ['K', 'K', '8', '10']

Comment: see my edit. now it just prints 5 lines per column

Comment: Hi
After my tests, there is one last drop in the direction. How can I set column 'a' to be always the first card of choice.
When there are 4 cards 1-2-3-4 card number 1. I realized that the parameter should be used
p = [1,0,0,0]
And I do not success

Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243856/discussion-between-sandwichnick-and-yon).

Comment: The rest of the cards continue to get selected from columns 'a' 'b'

Comment: I am very confused, you altered the original question to much. please edit the question to accurately reflect your problem now.

Comment: Sorry
To be precise in choosing the cards
the column A is Only for card 1 without column B.
And column B is only for card 2 without column A.
And the rest of the cards continue to be selected from columns A and B
3 4
For example
['J' '10' 'A' '7'] J is the first card and 10 is the second card
Thank you